# Should you split a 'Likes' table into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

Suppose I have a social network application similar to Instagram. For my database schema I would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `like_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int,
  `type` ENUM ('POST', 'COMMENT'),
  `target_id` int
);
```

in which target_id is a foreign key pointing to either a specific post or specific comment. Is this bad design to merge the post and comment likes into a single table and distinguish them by type ENUM? would it be better to create two tables: commentLikes and postLikes where there is no distinction?

Keep in mind that I do foresee in the future maybe adding more features to the app that they could like e.g. Articles or Recipes etc.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: While taking advice from the Answers, get rid of `like_id`; it's a lot of wasted overhead.  You have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`, use it.  In your example:  `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, type, target_id)`.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because "advice" is worth keeping.  I see the Question more along the lines of asking advice than opinion.  The responses give well-founded advice, presumably derived from years of experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I like conciseness of what you have, I'd recommend having commentlikes, postlikes and such tables separate from each other. That way, someone looking at your database can see comments table and find commentlikes table and can easily make sense of what's happening.

When joining tables, it's mentally easier to join comments table with commentlikes in a query.

You can get data from both a singular likes table and separate likes table equally easily, I'd say. For example, if you wanted to find which comment got the most likes, using the concise table you'd do:

```
select c.id
from comments c
inner join likes l on c.id = l.target_id and 'comment' = l.type
where l.added between x and y
```

If commentlikes was separate, you'd write:

```
select c.id
from comments c
inner join commentlikes l on c.id = l.target_id
```

Separate table allows you to define foreign key relationships. Foreign keys allow referential integrity and have a bit of performance overhead. You have to decide whether the overhead is significant enough in comparison to compromise of referential integrity (or adding additional code to compensate for RI right in the database).

You can also change behavior of likes between comments, posts etc. in a readable manner if the tables were separate. For example, if you want likes to be of different types (e.g. heart, congratulations, dislike etc.) for comments but not for posts, separate tables can allow that flexibility. You can do the same thing with a single table too. It'd be more readable if tables were separate.

If you get tons of likes on comments and posts, likes table will become large faster than if likes tables were separate.

You can start with a concise table and split it at an opportune time, or you could  start with different tables and combine it at a later time.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is fine.  What you want to do is -- unfortunately -- is not simple in SQL.  Ideally, you would like to have a foreign key relationship between `target_id` and the table it references.  With your structure, this is not possible.

However, your method does have the advantage of conciseness -- both in table definitions and in the underlying table layouts.  The cost is an inability to declare foreign key relationships.

EDIT:

If there were a simple alternative, I would suggest it.  You can have a separate column for each foreign key relationship, but that not only eats up space but it also makes it difficult to add a new relationship.  You could generate a column for a foreign key, but that is rather cumbersome and the columns should be persisted for the foreign key relationship.

There is not optimal solution, so your version is fine.  Other solutions are fine too, depending on what you need the solution to do.

Comment: I know its largely an opinion-based question but in your view would sacrificing the advantage of conciseness be worth the ability to declare foreign key relationships (which I presume will result in some kind of performance gain)?

I ask as I am just beginning my studies of database design and normalisation